# Returning a recordset from Oracle to .Net using an Oracle function that takes arguments

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-3.5, oracle11g, asp.net-3.5

I currently have the following funciton in an oracle database that returns a concatenated string seperated by pipes. It's a legacy application that is being updated to use .net 3.5. The exiisting application concatenates the returned result set into a VARCHAR2 data type. What I want to do is return the entire result set back to my .net client. The MS SQL equivalent of what I'm trying to accomplish is a simple "SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE id = @id" I'm not use to some of the concepts Oracle uses. I't seems like e blend of OOP and SQL querying. I've read multiple examples on this but can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for. Can you please help?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DOCSADMIN.GET_DOCS (
    RECID IN NUMBER) -- RECORD ID
    RETURN VARCHAR2 -- CONCATENATED STRING WITH PIPES
IS
    RETVAL          VARCHAR2(5000) :='';
    DOCSTRING       VARCHAR2(5000) :='';    
    DOCNAME      VARCHAR2(5000) :='';
    DOCNUMBER    NUMBER;
    STATUS       VARCHAR2(5000) :='';
    DOCTYPE      VARCHAR2(5000) :='';
    EDITDATE     DATE :='';
/******************************************************************************
   NAME:       GET_DOCS
   PURPOSE:    Pulls associated docs from profile table
******************************************************************************/


   CURSOR GETDOCINFO IS SELECT DOCNUMBER, DOCNAME, CUSTOM_STATUS, DOCUMENTTYPES.DESCRIPTION, LAST_EDIT_TIME
        FROM PROFILE, DOCUMENTTYPES, FORMS WHERE NAD_APID = IN_APID AND PROFILE.FORM = FORMS.SYSTEM_ID AND 
        DOCUMENTTYPE = DOCUMENTTYPES.SYSTEM_ID AND FORM_NAME = 'DOCS_PROFILE' ORDER BY DOCNUMBER;

BEGIN

    OPEN GETDOCINFO;
        --GET THE FIRST RECORD
        FETCH GETDOCINFO INTO DOCNUMBER, DOCNAME, STATUS, DOCTYPE, EDITDATE;
        --LOOP THROUGH ALL ASSOCIATED DOCS AND GRAB INFO
        WHILE GETDOCINFO%FOUND LOOP

            BEGIN

                DOCSTRING := DOCNUMBER || '|~|' || DOCNAME || '|~|' || STATUS || '|~|' || DOCTYPE || '|~|' || WS_EDITDATE;

                RETVAL := RETVAL || DOCSTRING || '|^|';

                GOTO STARTOVER;

            END;

            <<STARTOVER>>

            FETCH GETDOCINFO INTO DOCNUMBER, DOCNAME, STATUS, DOCTYPE, EDITDATE;

        END LOOP;

   CLOSE GETDOCINFO;

   RETURN RETVAL;

   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       NULL;
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging

 the error and then re-raise
       RAISE;
END GET_DOCS;
/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could convert the function in to a procedure and have an OUT parameter of the `SYS_REFCURSOR` type. With Oracle and .Net you can pass back a cursor and iterate through that as a reader.

Sample Oracle procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_PROCEDURE (
  out_DATA OUT SYS_REFCURSOR;
) AS
BEGIN
  OPEN out_DATA FOR
  SELECT col1,
         col2
    FROM TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_TABLE;
END test_procedure;
```

Sample .Net end:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection("connstring"))
using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  command.CommandText = "TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_PROCEDURE";
  command.Parameters.Add("out_DATA", OracleType.Cursor)
      .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

  connection.Open();
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  OracleDataReader reader = 
      command.Parameters["out_DATA"].Value as OracleDataReader;

  if (reader != null) {
    using (reader) {
      while(reader.Read()) {
        string col1 = reader["col1"] as string;
        string col2 = reader["col2"] as string;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Be sure to close the cursor after you're done using it (accomplished above by the `using (reader)` statement).

So in your case, you could probably create a procedure that outputs the original cursor in your function, then just iterate over the cursor in .Net as listed above. Just a note, the column names from the Oracle side are important and will match what you're using in .Net.

Comment: How would I call this using an openquery command from SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

What I have so far compiles fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DOCSADMIN.GET_DOCS_SP  ( IN_APID IN NUMBER,   out_DATA OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) 

AS 
BEGIN   

OPEN out_DATA FOR   

SELECT DOCNUMBER, DOCNAME, CUSTOM_STATUS, DOCUMENTTYPES.DESCRIPTION, LAST_EDIT_TIME
        FROM PROFILE, DOCUMENTTYPES, FORMS WHERE APID = IN_APID AND PROFILE.FORM = FORMS.SYSTEM_ID AND 
        DOCUMENTTYPE = DOCUMENTTYPES.SYSTEM_ID AND FORM_NAME = 'PROFILE' ORDER BY DOCNUMBER;

END GET_DOCS_SP;
```

/

However, I've run into another situation and would appreciate your input. If I wanted to call the following from a sql database using OPENQUERY how would I do so? The legacy version that was returning the concatenated string looked like the following.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (TESTSERVER, 'SELECT DOCSADMIN.GET_DOCS_SP (26) AS DOCINFO FROM DUAL')
```

Do I just remove the as DOCINFO FROM DUAL clause?

Thanks

Comment: I've never tried using OPENQUERY before, you may be able to use a wrapper (this is off the hip): `CREATE PROCEDURE DOCSADMIN.GET_DOCS_SP_OPENQUERY (IN_APID IN NUMBER) RETURNS SYS_REFCURSOR AS proc_result SYS_REFCURSOR; BEGIN DOCSADMIN.GET_DOCS_SP(IN_APID, proc_result); RETURN proc_result; END GET_DOCS_SP_OPENQUERY;` then from SQL `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(TESTSERVER, 'SELECT DOCSADMIN.GET_DOCS_SP_OPENQUERY(26) AS DOCINFO FROM DUAL')` That was written on the fly and may not even work.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much. I think the return value will work much better than the out parameter. Seems similar to C# syntax.